# Are procedures a type of variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make a list of variables that i have used in my code. I have used some procedures but i dont know if a procedure can be classed as a variable

Comment: Python doesn't have procedures, it has _functions_. And please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "procedure" in Python.  *Functions*, however, are [first class](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FirstClassFunction).